# Mysql syntax error for creating table

Tags: mysql, database, create-table

I want to create a table in mysql:--

```
create table app_own(app_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
sp_id bigint(20),
title varchar(30),
description varchar(60),
details LONGTEXT(1000),
primary key(app_id ),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES student(sp_id));
```

where **app_id**  is the primary key and **sp_id** is the foreign key reference from student table..

but  I am getting error:--

```
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
    manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
    syntax to use near '(1000)0,primary key(app_id ),FOREIGN KEY (sp_id) 
REFERENCE' at line 1
```

why the error is occuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Run This one:-

```
   use db;
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;

CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PID int UNSIGNED  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City longtext,
PRIMARY KEY (PID),
FOREIGN KEY (PID) 
        REFERENCES parent(id)
 ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

LONGTEXT [CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]

A TEXT column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 or 4GB (232 − 1) characters. The effective maximum length is less if the value contains multibyte characters. The effective maximum length of LONGTEXT columns also depends on the configured maximum packet size in the client/server protocol and available memory. Each LONGTEXT value is stored using a 4-byte length prefix that indicates the number of bytes in the value.

Comment: I have tried your code..I got message:--ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'mydatabase.persons' (errno: 150)

Comment: Have u used Unsigned for the primary key of parent table

Comment: Is there any table with the name Parent in the DB where u r trying to create table

Comment: Nopes..Its clean..I have copied and pasted your code

Comment: have u replaced db with ur dbname

Answer (score 0):

You should user `varchar(1000)` in place of `longtext(1000)`.

Moreover `user_id` column doesn't exist in you table.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t specify the `LONGTEXT` in this context. Have a look in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html).

Change your code to:

```
create table app_own(app_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
sp_id bigint(20),
title varchar(30),
description varchar(60),
details LONGTEXT,
primary key(app_id),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES student(sp_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you shouldn't be using spaces inbetween the brackets at primary key(app_id).